Why order type of union of canonical well-orderings is union of order types of canonical well-orderings
Let $\alpha \times \alpha$ be a pair in $Ord^2$. Define
$$\Gamma(\alpha \times \beta) = \text{order type of } \alpha \times \beta$$
Suppose $\alpha$ is limit ordinal. How do we have
$$\Gamma(\alpha \times \alpha) = \Gamma\bigg(\bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} \beta \times \beta\bigg) = \bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} \Gamma(\beta \times \beta)$$
? Why the two operations commute as shown in here(answer of @Clement Yung). I do understand why $\alpha \times \alpha = \bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} \beta \times \beta$

It's not true in general that $\Gamma(\alpha\times \beta)$ is equal to the order type of $\alpha \times \beta.$ It may not even be an ordinal in the case where $\alpha\ne\beta$. For instance, the order type of $(\omega+1)\times \omega$ is $\omega\cdot 2,$ whereas $$\Gamma((\omega+1)\times \omega) =[0,\omega)\cup[\omega\cdot 2,\omega\cdot 3),$$ since the elements with $\Gamma(\gamma,\delta)\in [\omega,\omega\cdot 2)$ are $(0,\omega), (1,\omega),(2,\omega)\ldots,$ which are not elements of $(\omega+1)\times \omega.$
The two operations commute because function images always commute with unions (this is for binary unions but the same argument works for arbitrary unions). Perhaps the problem (per the confusion pointed out in the previous paragraph) is that you are confused about the point that $\Gamma(\alpha\times \beta)$ denotes the image of the set $\alpha\times\beta$ under $\Gamma$. It is not the value of $\Gamma$ at the point $\alpha\times \beta$. This wouldn't make any sense since $\Gamma$ is a function $\mathrm{Ord}^2 \to \mathrm{Ord}.$

@MathInquirer I had not properly read your first sentence "Let $\alpha\times \alpha$ be a pair in Ord$^2$." This suggests you are misunderstanding Jech's notation more seriously than I originally thought. The notation $\times$ does not denote a pair, it is a Cartesian product. Very different thing.

You can even read the correct version of the definition $$\Gamma(\alpha,\beta):=\text{the order-type of},{(\xi,\eta):(\xi,\eta)<(\alpha,\beta)}$$ at the other post... note it's a comma, not a $\times.$ The notation $\Gamma(\alpha\times\beta)$ means the image of the set $\alpha\times \beta$  under $\Gamma.$ (where $\alpha\times \beta = {(\gamma,\delta): \gamma\in \alpha, \delta\in \beta}$)

I'll have a look. Thank you!

For future visitors: The function is onto due to $\Gamma(\alpha \times \alpha) = \alpha$ for arbitrarily large $\alpha$.
